# C++, decltype and constness error

Tags: c++

I can't understand why the following code is wrong.

```
struct A{
    typedef std::vector<std::vector<int>> Base;

    // const auto& func(std::size_t e) const
    auto func(std::size_t e) const -> decltype(std::declval<Base>()[e])
    {
            return base[e];
    }

    Base base;
};
```

I get compile error with the above snippet in gcc 4.8.1. (error: invalid initialization of reference of type '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits > >::value_type& {aka std::vector&}' from expression of type 'const value_type {aka const std::vector}'
   return base[e];)

Note that if I delete the `const` qualifier, it works fine.

But if I replace the part for function signiture by the commented one (to use the automatic type deduction introduced in C++14). No error is generated.
So, I guess the decltype part is wrong.

Comment: I think you need to have `auto func(std::size_t e) -> decltype(std::declval<Base>()[e]) const`, with `const` at the end.

Comment: @alfC : I checked your solution, but I get a different error. Let me be clear. I want to put `const` in the member function. not as a part of return type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
auto func(std::size_t e) const -> decltype(std::declval<const Base>()[e])
```

Comment: Oh thanks, I got it. I tried something similar before. That was replacing the `decltype` part as `std::add_const<decltype(std::declval<Base>()[e])>::type`. Do you know why my version did not work?

Answer (score 3):

Since `Base` is a non-const type, `std::declval<Base>()[e]` refers to a non-const version of `operator[]` of `std::vector`. That version of `[]` returns a non-const reference of type `std::vector<int> &`. So, the return type of your function is declared as `decltype(std::declval<Base>()[e])`, which is `std::vector<int> &`.

Meanwhile, your member function `func` is declared as `const`. It means that member `base` will have `const Base` type inside that member function. This in turn means that the application of operator `[]` to `base` will refer to const version of `operator []`. That version of `[]` returns the result of `const vector<int> &` type.

So, your `return` statement attempts to implicitly convert a `const vector<int> &` value to a `vector<int> &` value. This conversion is invalid. It violated the rules of const-correctness.

Either add `const` in the return type, as @catscradle suggested. Or remove `const` from method declaration

```
auto func(std::size_t e) -> decltype(std::declval<Base>()[e])
```

Either this or that.